# Is a correction needed in the weighting matrix when using the simulated method of moments?

Tags: econometrics, simulation, method-of-moments

I am following several guides on the simulated method of moments (SMM) and one practical way of getting the weighting matrix, W, is to bootstrap the empirical moments and invert their covariance matrix. My issue is that the elements of this matrix are very large (because the variances of the moments, and the moments themselves, are very small). This makes my SMM objective function quite large, even when the distance between empirical and simulated moments is fairly small. It seems to me that there ought to be some type of "correction" (for lack of a better word) in order to account for the scale of the weighting matrix. For example, if the elements of W are all around 5000 and simulated moments are all around 0.01 away from the true moments, the objective will be fairly large and may lead me to believe that I should reject my model. Am I misunderstanding something here?